# Mysqli construct warning ,The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]

Tags: php, mysql, apache, mysqli

I cannot find any answered questions on this specific issue, 
I am using php 7,mysql server and apache web server 
This is the code i use to connect to my database:

```
$servername = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = 'my_password';
$dbname = 'ehotels';

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

Comment: This is the common issue in all new MySQL server, I have posted an answer below that will solve your problem, If the information is useful you may upvote and mark it answered.